# Property of continuous second derivatives functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ a domain (open and connected) and $f:D \times D \to \mathbb{R}$ a function which has continuous second derivatives and $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ then

$$f(x,x) + f(y,y) - 2f(x,y) \leq C|x-y|^2 \hspace{1cm} \forall x,y \in D,$$

where $C$ is a positive constant.

I used the mean property in several variables but in order to conclude I need that the second derivate function of $f$ is bounded. I can't prove this without compactness of $D$. Is it possible that this result es false? In this case, do you know some similar result? I need to show this in order to get a continuous path of Gaussian processes with kernel convariance $f$.

Answer (score 1):

This is false even in very simple cases. Let $f(x,y)=x$. Then the inequality becomes $y-x \leq C|x-y|^{2}$ which is false.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one condition more: $f$ is symmetric: $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$.

Comment: Still false, take $f(x,y) = (xy)^2$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for your time. I took a lot of time trying to show that it was true.